# ¿Es correcto el uso del imperfecto del subjuntivo en oraciones condicionales?

Tags: subjuntivo

¿Es correcto el uso del imperfecto del subjuntivo en la siguiente frase?

> El policía amenazó con detener al borracho si no **parase** de molestar a los vecinos

No me suena del todo bien, pero no logro encontrar nada que me indique que no es correcto. Creo que lo correcto sería usar el pretérito imperfecto en este caso, pero quiero estar seguro:

> El policía amenazó con detener al borracho si no **paraba** de molestar a los vecinos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la Nueva Gramática, [epígrafe 47.8c](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=peoNhxjtfPZEEQPl), se explica que si el período condicional es independiente (en el sentido de no subordinado) se deben usar los tiempos verbales en indicativo y en relación con el presente de la enunciación. Cita como ejemplo:

> Si me lo explicas, lo entiendo/entenderé.

La cual en el discurso indirecto quedaría como:

> Le dije que si me lo explicaban, lo entendía/entendería.

Este tipo de oraciones se denominan de período real, y son las condicionales más simples, del tipo "si pasa A, pasa B". Nótese la diferencia con las de período potencial ("si pasara A, pasaría B") o irreal ("si hubiera pasado A, habría pasado B").

La oración que pones como ejemplo corresponde con un ultimátum del policía, y es de tipo "si pasa A, pasa B" siendo A "no te paras" y B "te arresto", solo que el discurso es indirecto y por tanto se usa un tiempo pasado. Por tanto, y respondiendo a tu pregunta: no, no sería correcto usar el subjuntivo dado que es una oración condicional con período real y en estas se deja claro que hay que usar el indicativo en las prótasis.

Nótese que esta construcción aplica solamente en el caso de condicionales con la conjunción *[si](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XmM8PPL)*, pero la frase se podría reescribir de otras formas que sí usan el subjuntivo:

> El policía amenazó con detener al borracho a menos que parase de molestar a los vecinos.
>   <sup>(Usa el subjuntivo porque el verbo *parar* va en una oración de relativo.)</sup>
>
> El policía amenazó con detener al borracho como no parase de molestar a los vecinos.
>   <sup>(*[Como](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWxEd9)* introduce apódosis condicionales pero requiere que el verbo esté en subjuntivo, ver acepción 13).</sup>

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! Entonces, si sustituimos "si no" por "a menos que", seguiría siendo un discurso indirecto? En este caso también sería "paraba" o se podría usar "parase"? "El policía amenazó con detener al borracho **a menos que** parase de molestar a los vecinos"

Comment: @mrleone he ampliado la respuesta para añadir el caso que comentas y otros.